# How to open dwg file in browser using bravia freeDWG

Tags: plugins, browser, dwg

I instal freeDWG.http://www.bravaviewer.com/viewers, it works realy nice when opening in as desktop application, but it seams that i can't figure out how to use it as web browser plugin.

I need to open dwg files in browser, so how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try browser plug-in from AutoDWG, it works very well for me, see: http://www.autodwg.com/dwg-viewer/dwgviewx.htm

All my dwg drawing files can be opened in my IE window, except for AutoCAD 2013 drawing files.

Comment: well i found the solution out, i needed to change some properities in IE, in mozzila it/s not working but i/m fine with ie. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Do you now any plugin that allow to open 3D CAD files?